# Chrome extension: communication between background and content scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to execute a content script from a background script with sending a couple of parameters from the background script to the content one. I explored a couple of help pages like this one ...

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi

... but still have no idea how to organize it. In a Firefox extension, I did the following:

*background script excerpt:*

```
browser.tabs.executeScript({
              file: "content/login.js"
            }).then(messageContent).catch(onError)
}

function messageContent() {

    var gettingActiveTab = browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});

    gettingActiveTab.then((tabs) => {
          browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {loginUserName: loginUserName, loginPassword: loginPassword});
                    });
}
```

*content script excerpt:*

```
function justDoTheJob(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    var doc = window.content.document;

    doc.getElementById("loginUserName").value = request.loginUserName;
    doc.getElementById("loginPassword").value = request.loginPassword;

}

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(justDoTheJob);
```

But when I do something like that in Chrome, I get the following:

*Error in response to tabs.query: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at Object.callback*

So it looks like I am using a wrong syntax or even wrong structure at all. Could you please give me some clue on how to do it properly?

Thanks,
Racoon

Comment: chrome API is not Promise-based so you need to switch to callbacks or use a [polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill).

Comment: Thanks. So how to use a callback with sending some parameters from a background script to a content one? Any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @qwOxxOm points out in comments, you need to use callbacks in Chrome, for example, instead of appending with `then()`, move the function inside `then` to the argument chain of the call itself. Otherwise it's used pretty much the same way:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "content/login.js"}, myCallback);

function callback(result) {
  // handle result here
}
```

or like:

```
function messageContent() {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
     // sendMessage here
  })
}
```

etc.

Error handling is a bit different as you would check [`lastError`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-lastError) instead of using a callback for it.

You can also use the `chrome` namespace for Firefox (there are some differences between the two browsers/namespaces in some areas you need to take into consideration).